# Expression Creator Program - C#

Tags: c#, .net, expression

I need to write a program in C# that facilitates the input of logical expression.

There is an operator set which includes >, <, >=, <=, =, !=
There are AND, OR and parenthesis.

There is going to be a menu that user can select operators and input the values to compare so that the output will be something like:

```
(A > 5) OR (B = 10 AND C != 50)
```

How would you suggest to do it in a way that user always has to input valid values. Do you know any articles about it?

Comment: You could ask your tutor for additional assistance.

Comment: There's no tutor. It's my job

Comment: Regular expressions? String substrings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is build an application that will allow users to build Expression Trees (within some constraints).

[Here is a really good article by Charlie Calvert describing what expression trees are](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/01/31/expression-tree-basics.aspx), how you might use them and how to build them.

I hope this gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: This is something I've done in the past to build a parser for a simple logical expression, combined with a recursive decent parser to build and walk the expression tree. Worked extremely well and ended up being fairly short easy to read code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should look at implementing a RDC.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

There are tons of articles on the web, just google.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) can solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This series may be of interest

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/26/every-program-there-is-part-one.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Windows  Workflow Activities Rule engine in the past.
It gives you an Excel/Access style GUI to define rules based on objects, but might offer a lot more than you need. 
Have a look [here](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/vagif/archive/2009/04/05/rule-engine-with-wysiwyg-rule-serialization.aspx) as a start.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Operator overloads are what you look for???

Something like:

```
internal class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public static bool operator >(Person thisPerson, int compareValue)
    {
        return thisPerson.Age > compareValue;
    }

    public static bool operator <(Person thisPerson, int compareValue)
    {
        return thisPerson.Age < compareValue;
    }

}
```